# What is the purpose of MemoizedSelector<type, type> in NgRx?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

So there's two ways to create a selector without specifying its type:

```
    export const mySelector = createSelector(getAnotherSelector, (anotherSelector) => {
        return anotherSelector * 2;
    });
```

and with:

```
    export const mySelector: MemoizedSelector<type, type> = createSelector(getAnotherSelector, (anotherSelector) => {
        return anotherSelector * 2;
    });
```

I've been experiencing some issues when using the `MemoizedSelector<type, type>` and I was wondering what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think typing selectors like this isn't needed. The types will be inferred from the result of the selector. To type the result of the selector I user/prefer the following:

```
export const mySelector = createSelector(getAnotherSelector, (anotherSelector): number => {
   return anotherSelector * 2;
});
```